# ionic checklist with object array - how to dertermine if checkbox is checked

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, checkbox, checkboxlist

my code app.js:

```
jt.controller('TheorieCtrl', function($scope, $window, $ionicPlatform) {
// .log($window.localStorage);
// Ready functions
if ($window.localStorage.getItem('themen') === null) {
    $scope.themen = [{
        name: "Setting1",
        checked: false
    }, {
        name: "Setting2",
        checked: false
    }
    ];
} else {
    $scope.themen = JSON.parse($window.localStorage['themen']);
};

$scope.updateThemaLocalStorage = function(items) {
    $window.localStorage['themen'] = JSON.stringify(items);
};
```

});

my html code:

```
 <ion-list>
    <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="thema in themen track by $index" class="checkbox-positive item-checkbox-right" type="checkbox" id="{{thema.id}}" ng-model="thema.checked" ng-change="updateThemaLocalStorage(themen)">
        {{ thema.name }}            
    </ion-checkbox>
</ion-list>
```

In a other controller I would like to determine if Setting1 is checked.
Is it something like:
if($scope.thema.Setting1.checked){ "do something" }
But this doesn't work. I just need help with syntax for this.

I guess this is a absolutely newbie question. sorry for that, I did really searched and tried a lot.

Comment: shouldn't `if($scope.thema.Setting1.checked){ "do something" }` be `if($scope.thema[0].name.checked){ "do something" }` if the array never changes.

Comment: thank you for your reply! It says "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: ok, error property 0 solved, now if I look at $scope.thema in log, it looks like this: 0: {name: "SanftesIntervall", checked: true}
1:{name: "IrgendeinSetting", checked: false}

Comment: if($scope.themen[0].checked){ "do something" } is working. thanks

Comment: cool, i will write in as an answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should just change the lookup. if the array never changes.

current:

```
if($scope.thema.Setting1.checked){ "do something" }
```

expected:

```
if($scope.thema[0].name.checked){ "do something" }
```